# How to restore system after removing initscripts

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I just wanted to see what would the command `sudo apt-get remove initscripts` would do and now I do not have `System Settings` and I don't know what such other essential parts of my ubuntu have gone missing. Please do tell me how can I restore them now.

I tried installing all the packages that the command 'sudo apt-get remove initscripts' removed. But no luck. [image]

It seems that I have many broken packages now

The output of `grep '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Add the output of `grep '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question.

Comment: @Ravexina added to the question :)

Comment: is your sources up to date? `sudo apt update`? do you have any PPA enabled?

Comment: Yes my sources are up to date

Comment: Add `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse` to your sources, update them try to install your packages again. it might help you.

Comment: @Ravexina Thanks a lot !!! It worked like a charm ! I was able to install all the removed packages :)

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful to you, I sent it as an answer so it might helps others too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your outputs, it seems to me that your sources are not complete and that is why `apt` complains about some packages that are not going to be installed.

Add these two lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main universe multiverse
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

Now try again to install recently removed packages. It should work now.

You can also take a look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see which packages has been removed with your `remove` command.